# Springboot 3 resttemplate unit test how to inject

Tags: spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

My environment is `Spring Boot` 3.0.5:

I need to implement Unit Test for a service method `login()` that use `RestTemplate`

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PosteDeliveryClientImpl.class)
public class DeliveryBusinessClientTests {

    @Autowired
    private PosteDeliveryClientImpl posteDeliveryClient;


    public DeliveryBusinessClientTests() {

    }

    @Test
    public void login() {

        var loginResponse = posteDeliveryClient.login();

        assertEquals("Bearer", loginResponse.getToken_type());
    }
```

The service is define as below:

```java
@Service
public class PosteDeliveryClientImpl implements  PosteDeliveryClient {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    ...

    @Override
    public LoginResponse login() {
        var loginRequest = new LoginRequest("xxxxxxxxxx",
                                            "xxxxxxxx",
                                            "api://xxxxxxxxxx/.default",
                                            "client_credentials");

        ResponseEntity<LoginResponse> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(ROOT_URI, loginRequest,        LoginResponse.class);
        return response.getBody();
    }

}
```

When i run test i receive:

```
Field restTemplate in it.posweb.service.pti.PosteDeliveryClientImpl 
required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.
```

How to solve injection correctly?

I try add bean on a config class but injection not works:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig extends RestTemplate {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }
}
```

Thanks
Daniele

:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you "only" `@SpringBootTest(classes = PosteDeliveryClientImpl.class)` (load selective classes/packages into spring test context), `RestTemplate` (auto/custom) configuration seems not to get picked up.

Possible solutions:

1. Import/re-use your `RestTemplate` (auto/custom) configuration:

   - via `@SpringBootTest#classes`
   - in any other possible/reasonable way...

   ((builder!) auto-configuration is ([currently](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/client/RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.html)) in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.client.RestTemplateAutoConfiguration` ;)
2. [Configure](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing) a new one:

   - a real one (based on custom/auto configuration)
   - a mock one...

Comment: Solved by  removing classes = PosteDeliveryClientImpl.class on @SpringBootTest annotation as suggested. Thanks

Comment: welcome! correct, that is the "sledge hammer" solution, but you pay with a "full context" for this (test). Smarter/thinner solution: import/declare it (restTermplate(builder) bean) selectively.